# Does a map service need write permissions for a file GDB?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-10.3, file-geodatabase, map-service

If an ArcGIS Map Service is published to use data located in a file geodatabase on a network drive, it obviously must be able to read from those files to present the data to end users. However, does it also need write access to the file GDB? I could imagine this being required for creating or modifying lock files, for instance.

I've found two pages of ESRI's documentation for ArcMap, but it's not clear whether they apply to ArcGIS Server:

- [File geodatabases and locking](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases-and-locking.htm) doesn't explicitly say. The note about creating lock files "on access" would suggest perhaps it is needed, but this still isn't explicit.
- [File geodatabases and Windows Explorer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/administer-file-gdbs/file-geodatabases-and-windows-explorer.htm#ESRI_SECTION1_AEED944E1C1F48F9901960FF5611FA62) says that you can set the file permissions to read only, but this is for ArcMap.

I'm using ArcGIS 10.3.

#### Side note

I'm well aware that serving up map service data from the network drive is typically not the best idea. Unfortunately, I am not the developer who designed or built the system, and I am tasked with deploying it without being given the opportunity to change this.

For future readers: **If you have a choice, don't store map service data in a file GDB on a network drive.** It's not good for performance.

Comment: ArcGIS for Server will want to lock data sources, but you can disable that, and if the source is read-only, the reason behind locking is moot (but don't start editing is from other platform later, because it won't like that).

Comment: Isn't it wise, for performance reasons, to keep file geodatabases on disk local to your ArcGIS Server rather than placing them on a network drive.

Comment: @PolyGeo Most certainly. Or even better to use actual databases for serving up this data. Sadly, the developers architecting the software involved chose this route, and I'm stuck with deploying it. I'll only be allowed to change it if it fails utterly.

Comment: My understanding is that file geodatabases give great performance as long as they are local to ArcGIS Server but put them on a network drive and your developers' architecture may need to be revised.

Comment: @PolyGeo The system as built uses an ArcObjects based scheduled task running on a separate machine to periodically generate the data. When it's done, it calls a geoprocessing service on the ArcGIS server, which uses the data off the network drive to recompute class breaks in MXDs and publishes new services. So the server needs access to the data before publishing. I was also told that the republish didn't update the data when ArcGIS was allowed to copy it. I would love to rip this apart and rebuild it in some sane way, but that is not an option the managers want to consider right now.